# mount returns errno 11 when mounting /dev or /proc

Tags: linux, mount, proc, initramfs

Recently I tried to create a minimal linux distro, that can run only a single program. I started by compiling the linux kernel and creating the initramfs. The initramfs contains /init (compiled c script), /proc (empty directory), /dev (another empty directory) and /sys (again, just an empty directory). It all worked fine until I tried to mount /proc with the C line

```
mount("/proc", "/proc", "proc", MS_NOATIME, NULL);
```

but it returned errno 11. Then I tried to mount /dev first with the line

```
mount("-", "/dev", "devtmpfs", MS_NOATIME, NULL);
```

but it also returned errno 11.
Does anyone have any ideas how to fix it? Btw, for the configuration, the system doesnt have anything that isnt described in this post and it was only tested in QEMU at this moment (I am going to try it on a real hardware after posting this question). The mentioned mounting code is on top of my script (the first line of the main function)

Update: After testing on a real computer, the error code was gone. Thus I would like to change my question. Why does QEMU behave in this strange way?